# Can Microsoft Visual Studio Web Performance Test Recorder save file from the Internet Explorer to local disk?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, load-testing, performance-testing

I'm using a Web Performance Test Recorder  to do a load test.
My customer is requesting to save a PDF file being displayed on the IE.
Is that possible to be done by the Web Performance Test alone ?
if not is there any possible solution for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in way to save responses as far as I know.  You would have to write a WebTestRequestPlugin to write the response to a file.

Here is a naive implementation as a starting point.

```
public class SaveResponsePlugin : WebTestRequestPlugin
{
    [DisplayName("File Name")]
    [Description("Name of file in which to save the response")]
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public override void PostRequest(object sender, PostRequestEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ResponseExists && !e.Response.IsBodyEmpty)
            File.WriteAllBytes(this.FileName, e.Response.BodyBytes);
    }
}
```